# Determine all functions $f:\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Q}$ satisfying the functional equation $f(2f(x) + f(y)) = 2x + y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, functional-equations

> Determine all functions $f$ defined on the set of rational numbers that take
>   rational values for which
>   $$f(2f(x) + f(y)) = 2x + y \tag{1}$$
>   for each x and y.

This question is from the 2008 Canada National Olympiad.

*The form of the defining equation strongly suggests a linear function, and that's all I found. Is there a trick somewhere that admits another class of solutions?*

---

Since $x,y\in\mathbb{Q}$ but otherwise take on all possible values, we are free to impose constraints at will.

$$x=y=0: f(3f(0))=0 \tag{2}$$

$$y=x: f(3f(x))=3x \tag{3}$$

$$x=0: f(2f(0)+f(y))=y \tag{4}$$

$$y=0: f(2f(x)+f(0))=2x \tag{5}$$

<del>By (5) and (2)</del>See $\color{blue}{\text{grand_chat}}$'s reasoning:

$$f(x)=0 \implies x=0 \tag{6}$$

So then by (2) <del>again</del>:

$$f(0) = 0 \tag{7}$$

Put $y=2x$ in (4) and equate to (5):

$$\begin{align}
& f(2f(0)+f(2x)) = f(2f(x)+f(0))  \\
\implies & 2f(0)+f(2x) = 2f(x)+f(0) &(\color{blue}{\text{f invertible}}) \\
\implies & 2f(x)-f(2x) = f(0) = 0 \\
\implies & f(x)=kx \tag{8}
\end{align}$$

Now by (3):

$$f(3f(x))=f(3kx)=3k^2x=3x \implies x=0 \lor k=\pm1$$

Therefore $$\boxed{f(x)=kx,\quad k\in\{-1,1\}}$$

Comment: I don't quite see your logic in (6). How does $f(x) = 0, f(f(0)) = 2x$ and $f(3f(0)) = 0$ imply that $x = 0$? It may be true (I haven't pushed through), but it isn't obvious.

Comment: If $f(x)=0$ for some $x$, then the LHS of eqn(5) becomes f(3f(0)) which is both equal to $2x$ in eqn(5) and to $0$ in eqn(2). So, this can only happen when $x=0$.

Comment: If $f(x_0) = 0$ then LHS of (5) becomes $f(f(0)) = 2x_0$. So, how can we conclude that $x_0 = 0$?

Comment: @GAVD - You're right. I think it was confirmation bias on my part (or just a terribly careless substitution). In any case, I think the best approach is to first prove that $f$ is injective as grand_chat did.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First establish that $f$ is one-to-one: If $f(x)=f(y)=a$, then by (1) we have $f(3a)=2x+y$. Interchanging $y$ and $x$ in (1) yields $f(3a)=2y+x$, hence $x=y$.

To show that $f(x)=0$ implies $x=0$, suppose $f(x)=0$. Then by (3), $f(0)=3x$. Put this into (2) to get $f(9x)=0$. But $f$ is one-to-one, so $x=0$.

We then get $f(0)=0$ by (2).  Put this into (4) to obtain
$$f(f(y))=y \quad\mbox{for all $y$}. \tag{*}$$

Apply $f$ to both sides of (5) and use (*) to obtain $2f(x)=f(2x)$. Apply $f$ to both sides of (1) and use (*) to obtain $f(2x)+f(y)=f(2x+y)$, from which we conclude that $f$ is linear.

From here, do the usual argument that $f(rx)=rf(x)$ for all integer $r$, and then that this holds for all rational $r$. Put $x=1$ to get that $f(r)=rf(1)$, i.e., $f(x)=kx$ for some rational $k$. Continue from here to your conclusion that $k$ equals $1$ or $-1$.

Comment: Thanks. That's a good argument that $f$ is one-to-one, which was needed to prove that $f$ is linear..